# combing hexadecimal values sent by socket

Tags: c, sockets, hex

i am working on a socket application in which client is sending packets containing hexadecimal values.What i want to do is to combine 2 hexadecimal values sent by the packet, divide it by 1000 and print the result as floating point value.

Suppose client sent data as 0x24,0x00 which is 36 and 00 in decimal and my server stored these values in char rdata[2].I have to combine these two hexadecimal values to form 3600 and divide it by 1000 to print result as 3.600.
I just need the help for c code to print the result as above not for recieving the data and all.
Thanku.
I am just giving a small part of code because the ehole application is of more than 1000 lines

```
Client
void analogdata(int sockfd,int confd)
{

char responsedata[]=[0x7E,0x11,0x01,0xD0,0x00,0xE0,0x02,0x24,0x00,0x0B,0x00,0x44,0x0C,0x34,0x00,0x32,0x00,0x14,0x00,0x32,0x0C,0x22,0x86,0x32,0x00,0x62,0x02,0x4D,0x02,0x0D];
int rc;
rc=send(sockfd,responsedata,sizeof(responsedata),0);
if(rc<0)
{
    perror("error in sending\n");
    close(confd);
    close(sockfd);
    exit(-1);
}
else 
printf("data successfully send\n");

}


Server    
void identifycmd(char command[],int acceptsd,int sd)

 {
int rc,i;
if(command[11]=='8' && command[12]=='2')
{
    char responsedata[30];
    rc=recv(acceptsd,responsedata,sizeof(responsedata),0);
    if(rc<0)
    {
        perror("error in recieving\n");
        close(acceptsd);
        close(sd);
        exit(-1);
    }

    checkretval(responsedata);
    processanalogdata(responsedata);

}   

if(command[11]=='8' && command[12]=='3')
{
    char responsedata[31];
    rc=recv(acceptsd,responsedata,sizeof(responsedata),0);
    if(rc<0)
    {
        perror("error in recieving\n");
        close(acceptsd);
        close(sd);
        exit(-1);
    }
    checkretval(responsedata);
    processinfostate(responsedata);

}


}
void processanalogdata(char responsedata[])
{


printf("response data is \n");
puts(responsedata);
printf("\n");
printf("*****Battery Analog Data*****\n");
printf("\n");
    printf("Max cell voltage is %.1f%d volt\n",(responedata[7]/10.0),responsedata[8]);
 }
```

Comment: Can you post some code effort?

Comment: Updated with some codee effort..

Comment: `(100*rdata[0] + rdata[1])/1000.0`

Comment: or `(100*(unsigned)rdata[0] + (unsigned)rdata[1])/1000.0`

Answer (score 0):

Without any further information I
 would try something like this.

```
   char *rdata[2] = {"0x24", "0x00"};                                              

   int a = 0;                                                                      
   int b = 0;                                                                      

   sscanf(rdata[0],"%x",&a);                                                       
   sscanf(rdata[1],"%x",&b);                                                       

   char *tmp = malloc(sizeof(char)*4);                                             
   sprintf(tmp,"%02i%02i",a,b);                                                    
   printf("%s \n",tmp);                                                            

   int value = atoi(tmp);                                                          

   printf("Result = %3.3f\n",value/1000.f);
```